# I want to have Custom Keycloack Authentication/Authorization or Identity Provider

Tags: keycloak, keycloak-services

I'm googling since long and i'm bit confused now should i create Custom iDP or Authentication provider in Keycloak.

**Below is my requirements.**

I have multiple clients and each client having login API which also returns JWT token on successful login so what business needs is that when user try to login i want keycloack to consume client API to Authenticate User and once user successfully authenticated by Client API Keycloack should generate token for further operations.

One more problem is can i use same token return from client as Keycloack token because there are some apis on client side which decode token and use some info from token.

Please suggest and i'm bit stressed to looking for different solution and couldn't help. I will be grateful if you can share sample code with it.

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by "I have multiple clients and each client having login API" (does that mean different endpoints secured by different realms?? I supose that's not what you want).

What you mention here:

*"what business needs is that when user try to login i want keycloack to consume client API to Authenticate User and once user successfully authenticated by Client API Keycloack should generate token for further operations."*

that is indeed the standard behaviour of Keycloak, why do you need a custom Authentication (user federated Authentication/ identity Provider)? You haven't made clear from the description of your problem, why do you need a custom Identity Provider SPI /custom Authentication federation? If you really need an Authentication SPI, please read chapter 8 from here:
 https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_development/index.html#_auth_spi

that's the best documentation on that topic. Are you authenticating against a custom Auth service of your company that doesn't support openid connect? If not, then you don't need a custom Authentication SPI.

regarding:

*"can i use same token return from client as Keycloack token because there are some apis on client side which decode token and use some info from token."*

I don't know exactly what you mean there, but depending on your client adapter there are slight variations on the way you get/extract a bearer token & secure your endpoints in general. Plase read chapter 3.1 from here: https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/securing_apps/index.html#_client_registration

There you'll find base implementations/suggestions for the different client adapters, or at least should move you forward in your search.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks, @tony_008 yes that's what I did. I have Custom Authentication SPI for each client. which also needs client-based authentication flow both (Browser and Direct)